# Why are Random Forests easier to parallelize than Gradient Boosted Machines?

Tags: machine-learning, parallel-processing, random-forest, gbm

Is it because GBMs, each decision tree is dependent on the previous decision trees? In other words, there is no independence?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already suspected, it is exactly because in GBM, each decision tree *depends* on the previous ones, so the trees cannot be fit independently, thus parallelization is in principle not possible.

Consider the following excerpt, quoted from [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/), Ch. 10 (Boosting and Additive Trees), pp. 337-339 (emphasis mine):

> A weak classifier is one whose error rate is only slightly better than
>   random guessing. The purpose of boosting is to **sequentially** apply the
>   weak classification algorithm to repeatedly modified versions of the data,
>   thereby producing a **sequence** of weak classifiers Gm(x), m = 1, 2, . . . , M. The predictions from all of them are then combined through a weighted
>   majority vote to produce the final prediction. 
>   [...]
>   Each **successive** classifier is thereby forced to concentrate on those training observations that are missed by previous ones in the sequence.

In a picture (ibid, p. 338):

[image]

In Random Forest, on the other hand, all trees are **independent**, thus the parallelization of the algorithm is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Isn't though possible to achieve parallelization on the tree level?

Comment: @adosar indeed it is (I think that this is what XGBoost and later packages do), but this would be equally applicable to both algos (GBM & RF), while the question here is why the latter is easier to parallelize than the former.